# Create an ImageView and put it in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

i need to show some images in a ScrollView with a LinearLayout, i have this in the xml.

```
    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/HorizontalS"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Relative1">
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and this in the .java file

```
    LinearLayout oneLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative1);

    //CREA EL IMAGEVIEW
    ImageView mImage = new ImageView(this);

    //CREA EL DRAWABLE Y LO SETEA EN EL IMAGEVIEW
    try {
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("mc/mc1.jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return;
    }

    //INGRESA LOS PARAMETROS Y LA IMAGEN AL LAYOUT
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    oneLayout.addView(mImage, lp);
```

this is not working, the program doesnt show the image :c

Thx for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see what really happens?

Comment: yes but i dont understand the debug process

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move to another solution?

from what i can understand you need to swipe between some images, so that, you can do this with ViewFlipper and define all your images in the xml layout

Comment: because i need to get the images from a folder, dynamically. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
LinearLayout oneLayout;
ImageView mImage;
/**
* Called when the activity is first created.
*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         oneLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative1);

        //CREA EL IMAGEVIEW
        mImage = new ImageView(this);
        mImage.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        //CREA EL DRAWABLE Y LO SETEA EN EL IMAGEVIEW
        try {
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("mc/mc1.jpg");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            return;
        }
        oneLayout.addView(mImage);
}
```